# Where is the .NET 2.0 GAC under Windows Server 2003?

Tags: .net, windows-server-2003, gac

I'm looking for the GAC under Windows Server 2003 and I can only find the GAC for .Net 1.1

Where can I find this folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

c:\windows\Assembly?

On the command line you can browse to different folders, though I'd use the gacutil to work with the gac, not a command line/ explorer.